# Wrong Return Value for I2C_SLAVE and I2C_RDWR on Raspberry pi

Tags: c, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, i2c

I am using Raspberry pi for I2C communication to a chip.

The I2C Runs on i2c-1 and the chip I want to communicate is mux0 for which the address is specified. I used a wrong address to see what value I get from I2C_SLAVE and I2C_RDWR.

I want to check if the I'm opening correct bus or not. So I'm using the if statement and it's working fine for me. 
`

```
int file;
file = open(i2c_adapt, O_RDWR);
if (file == -1)
  {
    perror("Check I2C Bus");
    exit(1);
  }
```

`

Then I saw there are two functions I can use to define the chip address. I2C_SLAVE and I2C_RDWR.

I want to check if the chip address is correct or not but both of them return same values.

I printed their return value to check.

`

```
printf("\nThe file value when Mux0 is %d", open("/dev/i2c-1", O_RDWR));
printf("\nThe file value of random bus is %d\n", open("/dev/i2c-0", O_RDWR));
printf("\nThe i2c_Slave value when Mux0 is %d", ioctl(file, I2C_SLAVE, mux0));
printf("\nThe i2c_Slave value of random address is %d\n\n", ioctl(file, I2C_SLAVE, 0x60));
printf("\nThe I2C_RDWR value when Mux0 is %d", ioctl(file, I2C_RDWR, mux0));
printf("\nThe i2c_RDWR value of random address is %d\n\n", ioctl(file, I2C_RDWR, 0x60));
```

When I run these commands I get the following values:

The file value when Mux0 is 4
The file value of random bus is -1

so I can use if statement to see if I'm using wrong bus

The i2c_Slave value when Mux0 is 0
The i2c_Slave value random address is 0

The i2c_RDRW value when Mux0 is -1
The i2c_RDRW value  of random address is -1[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9fux.png)

Can someone tell me why I'm getting same value for wrong chip as well?

Answer (score 0):

The `I2C_SLAVE` ioctl does not check if the slave address is present. It sets the default I2C slave address for the opened file, i.e. it sets the I2C slave address that `read()` and `write()` use.  The ioctl will return -1 and set `errno` to `EBUSY` if a device with the specified slave address is bound to a driver.

You are using the `I2C_RDWR` ioctl with a totally wrong third parameter. Check the documentation: [I2C Device Interface](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/i2c/dev-interface.html). The third argument points to a `struct i2c_rdwr_ioctl_data` which contains a pointer to an array of `struct i2c_msg` and the length of the array. Each `struct i2c_msg` contains a slave address, some flags, a buffer length and a buffer pointer. You can see an example of how to use it in [i2ctransfer.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/i2c-tools/i2c-tools.git/plain/tools/i2ctransfer.c) from the [i2c-tools](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/i2c-tools/i2c-tools.git/) git repository.

Comment: so if you look at the [link](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/i2c/dev-interface.html) you'll see they used the same function: 
`int addr = 0x40; /* The I2C address */

if (ioctl(file, I2C_SLAVE, addr) < 0) {
  /* ERROR HANDLING; you can check errno to see what went wrong */
  exit(1);
}`.

My question is they're also passing the same argument for i2c address as I am. For me the condition if (ioctl(file, I2C_SLAVE, addr) < 0 is not working.

Comment: @Inam They both use `ioctl` if that's what you mean. `ioctl` is a generic device I/O control command. The second parameter is the ioctl command code. The third parameter depends on the ioctl command code. Depending on the command, the third parameter will be a long or unsigned long integer, or a pointer to something, or not present. The prototype for the `ioctl` function is `int ioctl(int fd, unsigned long request, ...);` so the type of the third parameter is not fixed.

Comment: My question is just like I can check the return value of open function when I open i2c bus i.e it returns a -1 if wrong bus value is given.

How can i check if the address of device I want to communicate is present or not?

Comment: So please look at [link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) and the return value of ioctl. 

It says it returns -1 when there is error.

so my device address is 0x70

if i use ioctl(file, I2C_SLAVE, 0x70) it should return a non negative number. It returns 0.

if i use a fake address ioctl(file, I2C_SLAVE, 0x20) it should return -1 but it returns me a 0.

Comment: `ioctl(file, I2C_SLAVE, addr);` doesn't try and detect if a device with the given address is present, it only checks if the address is a sensible number and checks if the address is in use by a device bound to a device driver. Therefore, calling it with an address that is not present on the bus is not considered an error and the function returns 0.

Comment: For checking whether a device at a a slave address is present, you can try doing an I2C transfer and check if the transfer is successful. That is basically what the [i2cdetect](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/i2c-tools/i2c-tools.git/plain/tools/i2cdetect.c) program does. But be warned that some devices may lock up, or the I2C bus may lock up, when doing the generic detection techniques that i2cdetect uses.

Comment: Yes thank you. It helps. :) 

Sorry I'm new to this kernel thing .. Thanks anyway